# how to render data generated by text-editor

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, text-editor, rich-text-editor, tinymce-react

I am using [this](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/) (Tiny) text editor in the web platform. Able to integrate basic editor also
[image] Now problem i am facing is how to render output html data(which is in the string format) like this

[image]

so output data in string format is like this :
[image]

please help me out to render this string formatted data in a separate  block.

whole idea is like this i need a rich text editor like **stackoverflow/medium** and want to render the data in a separate location. I'm little confused about all this please help me out or suggest a better approach to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for getting content from the TinyMCE editor, and setting it in a new block.

One method could be to take the variable that has the string content you want to set in TinyMCE, and set it in the editor using [the insert content API](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#insertContent) method:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent(<your-string-in-var>);
```

You could also use the execCommand API to set a block within the editor first if you need:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('InsertHTML', false, '<div></div>');
tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent(<your-string-in-var>);
```

If you want to get the content and put it somewhere on the page, as you mention stackoverflow and medium, you can run the getContent API. Here's [a guide on getting content from the editor](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/?/?utm_source=google_ads&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_campaign=%5Bds%5D_dynamic_search_cn&utm_term=&utm_content=%5Bds%5D_consideration_ad5&gclid=Cj0KCQjwn9CgBhDjARIsAD15h0Cttn8U8VuSDEoc7V0MKvntpavmj3iXSb4eB48ZHPJSdWP496jrUdcaApWlEALw_wcB) to put somewhere else.